# Libgdx How to attach an object to a rotating circle

Tags: libgdx

I have a rotated circle and a sprite I want to attach the sprite to the point of collision with the rotated circle what is the math equation for doing this task

Comment: I think your question would  suit better at: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set origin of sprite to the collision coordinates. And then rotate it.

Comment: For example, if you have collision coordinates (x,y), than you should set origin of you sprite set to (x,y) by using mySprite.setOrigin(x,y) method.